# Why there is no $u$ channel in fermion-antifermion scattering, but there is a $u$ term in $|M|^2$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams

I'm studying the Yukawa Lagrangian $g\phi\bar\psi\psi$:

For ferimon-antifermion scattering, David Tong's QFT notes (p.121) have these Feynman diagrams:

[image]

We can relabel the momenta and redraw the two diagrams as follows (t and s):

[image]

My first question is why there is no u channel for this process. My intuition is if we want the u channel, we will have to switch p2 and p4 in t channel. However, this will require $\psi\psi\phi$ or $\bar\psi\bar\psi\phi$ term, so this is not correct.

If we define $t = (p_1-p_3)^2, s = (p_1+p_2)^2, u = (p_1-p_4)^2 $, then we can find
$$
|M|^2 = \frac{1}{2}g^4[3(t - 4m^2)^2 + 3(s - 4m^2)^2 + (u - 4m^2)^2]
$$

I think the definition of $u$ here makes me feel like there is a $u$ channel (drawn above), but isn't it the same as the $t$ channel, just with different labeling?

My question is if the $u$ channel exists in this process, and if not, why there is still a $u$ term in $|M|^2$ ?

Comment: There is no $u$ channel in a charged process like this for the reason you mention. This has no relation to whether $u$ appears in a particular person's favorite way of writing the amplitude. Mandelstam variables are not independent.

Comment: @Connor Behan Thank you!!